# How can I count how many times value X is used in column1, when column2="Y"?

Tags: mysql

I also need to group that info by Column3.

I could do it almost everything, except for "when column2="y". The code I've tried is this one:

```
select column3 ,count(column1) as asd 
from maps
group by column3;
```

If my table is, for example,

```
Month | Day          |  Column3
1     | Sun                YES
1     | Mon                NO 
1     | Tue                NO 
1     | Wed                YES 
1     | Thu                YES
1     | Fri                NO 
1     | Sun                YES
1     | Mon                YES
1     | Tue                YES
2     | Wed                NO
```

I expect for example, looking for the times where Column3= "YES", group by Day, when month=1. Thus, I expect to obtain something like this

```
Month | Day          |     asd
1     | Sun                2
1     | Mon                1
1     | Tue                1
1     | Wed                1
1     | Thu                1
1     | Fri                0
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you use a where clause.

```
select column3 ,count(column1) as asd 
from maps
where column2 = 'y'
group by column3;
```

So maybe, given this: Column3= "YES", group by Day, when month=1.:

```
select day ,count(*) as count 
from maps
where month = 1 and column3 = 'YES'
group by day;
```